# Formula for Nicolosi Globular Projection

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, cartography

What is the formula for the Nicolosi Globular projection?

In other words, what is the function that maps the coordinate `(φ, λ)` on the sphere to the coordinate `(x, y)` on the plane?

[Example of a Nicolosi Globular projection](http://map-projections.net/img/rot-w/nicolosi-globular-110w.png)

You can assume that there are two such functions, one for each of the two hemispheres of the projection, such that the origin `(x = 0, y = 0)` in both cases is in the center of the given hemisphere.

Comment: I was surprised I couldn't find an easy answer to this. Since proj4 recognizes it, the source code does include a conversion routine (https://github.com/route-me/route-me/blob/master/Proj4/PJ_nocol.c) but it'll require some work to extract a formula from that code. Note: this question crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672580/formula-for-nicolosi-globular-projection

Comment: It's in Voxland and Snyder's [An Album of Map Projections](http://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1453/report.pdf), p234 (pdf). Because there are 7-8 equations plus references to two other Globular projections, I'm not reproducing here. There's no inverse listed.

Comment: There's an alternative version of the forward Nicolosi equations in Fenna's _Cartographic Science_ (2007, ISBN 9780849381690).

From that one can work out the inverse for getting the longitude from x and y, but getting the latitude apparently takes an iterative procedure.

Answer (score 1):

> Not a proper answer, but may help to end up with mapping procedure

Formulas from [the book](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1453/report.pdf) mentioned above by [@mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/963/mkennedy) were successfully executed by Torben Jansen on Observable in the article [Nicolosi globular projection](https://beta.observablehq.com/@toja/nicolosi-globular-projection) with the implementation of JavaScript and D3 library.

Moreover, it also includes Nicolosi hemispheres shown with an example.